# Defining Control-Shift-* Emacs keyboard shortcuts

Tags: emacs, keyboard-shortcuts

I'm trying to define the following two keyboard shortcuts to move between windows in Emacs:

- `C-shift-n:` Move to the next window
- `C-shift-b:` Move to the previous window

I thought the following will do it but it doesn't.

```
(defun select-next-window ()                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               
  "Switch to the next window"                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
  (interactive)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               
  (select-window (next-window)))                                                          

(defun select-previous-window ()                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
  "Switch to the previous window"                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
  (interactive)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
  (select-window (previous-window)))        

(global-set-key (kbd "C-<S-n>") 'select-next-window)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
(global-set-key (kbd "C-<S-p>") 'select-previous-window)
```

The problem seems to be with the last two lines that define the actual keyboard shortcuts to the functions that switch the windows (if I use simpler keyboard shortcuts instead of  `Control-Shift-*` it works).

So, how do I use `kbd` to define `Control-Shift-n` and `Control-Shift-p`?

Comment: In general, use `C-h k` to find out how Emacs refers to a given key combination, and then pass that exact string into `(kbd)`. There are other ways of specifying keys, but I think this symmetry makes `kbd` the best option.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assuming you never use caps lock, here's a super simple solution:

```
(global-set-key (kbd "C-N") 'select-next-window)
```

or

```
(global-set-key (kbd "C-<S-N>") 'select-next-window)
```

The problem is that when you hit shift you're sending capital N.

Comment: Sorry, I just realized why. I was running Emacs inside Terminator, which apparently captures `C-S-N` and `C-S-P`. Thanks!

Comment: Do you have caps lock on or something? I have the first one running right now.

Comment: @why it returns emacs' internal representation of whatever key-string you give it. so (kbd "C-N") returns ^N. You can find this by hitting `Control-h f`, `kbd`